# Using JWT during SignalR connection with Blazor-WASM

Tags: jwt, signalr, blazor, blazor-client-side

I'm messing with Blazor + SignalR connection. I'd want to Authorize calls to SignalR by using JWT.

Basically I want to attach to SignalR calls the JWT

Here's my Blazor WASM SignalR Code

```
@page "/"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
@implements IDisposable

<div class="form-group">
    <label>
        User:
        <input @bind="userInput" />
    </label>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>
        Message:
        <input @bind="messageInput" size="50" />
    </label>
</div>
<button @onclick="Send" disabled="@(!IsConnected)">Send</button>

<hr>

<ul id="messagesList">
    @foreach (var message in messages)
    {
        <li>@message</li>
    }
</ul>

@code {
    private HubConnection hubConnection;
    private List<string> messages = new List<string>();
    private string userInput;
    private string messageInput;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .WithUrl(NavigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri("/chathub"))
            .Build();

        hubConnection.On<string, string>("ReceiveMessage", (user, message) =>
        {
            var encodedMsg = $"{user}: {message}";
            messages.Add(encodedMsg);
            StateHasChanged();
        });

        await hubConnection.StartAsync();
    }

    Task Send() =>
        hubConnection.SendAsync("SendMessage", userInput, messageInput);

    public bool IsConnected =>
        hubConnection.State == HubConnectionState.Connected;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _ = hubConnection.DisposeAsync();
    }
}
```

But I'm not sure how to attach JWT to this

I've seen this in Js version in section

`Bearer token authentication` in

```
this.connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl("/hubs/chat", { accessTokenFactory: () => this.loginToken })
    .build();
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-3.1#authenticate-users-connecting-to-a-signalr-hub

What's Blazor's way of doing this?

I tried this:

```
var token = "eyJhb(...)";

hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
.WithUrl($"{Configuration["Url"]}/chathub", (HttpConnectionOptions x) =>
{
    x.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer: {token}");
})
.Build();
```

But it threw error:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
Unhandled exception rendering component: The format of value 'Bearer: eyJh' is invalid.
System.FormatException: The format of value 'Bearer: eyJhbG' is invalid.
```

Comment: @HenkHolterman That would be weird, because I'm using that token inside `Insomnia` to ping an endpoint with `Authorize` attribute and it works fine, meanwhile without this token I'm receiving `Unauthorized`. I also tried it on `jwt.io` and it says that `signature verified` (OK) so seems like token is OK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was... to read the docs

```
var token = "eyJ";

hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .WithUrl($"{Configuration["Url"]}/chathub?access_token={token}")
    .Build();
```

Token is provided at connection estabilishing via url

We need to modify startup.cs to support `OnMessageReceived`

docs url:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-3.1#authenticate-users-connecting-to-a-signalr-hub

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    // Identity made Cookie authentication the default.
    // However, we want JWT Bearer Auth to be the default.
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    // Configure the Authority to the expected value for your authentication provider
    // This ensures the token is appropriately validated
    options.Authority = /* TODO: Insert Authority URL here */;

    // We have to hook the OnMessageReceived event in order to
    // allow the JWT authentication handler to read the access
    // token from the query string when a WebSocket or 
    // Server-Sent Events request comes in.

    // Sending the access token in the query string is required due to
    // a limitation in Browser APIs. We restrict it to only calls to the
    // SignalR hub in this code.
    // See https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/signalr/security#access-token-logging
    // for more information about security considerations when using
    // the query string to transmit the access token.
    options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
    {
        OnMessageReceived = context =>
        {
            var accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];

            // If the request is for our hub...
            var path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken) &&
                (path.StartsWithSegments("/hubs/chat")))
            {
                // Read the token out of the query string
                context.Token = accessToken;
            }
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: You should still use the `accessTokenFactory` on the client, it's a lot cleaner than putting a query string in your url. Plus, it'll make use of headers instead of the query string when possible.

Comment: @Brennan Could you show me an example? I couldnt find that class

Comment: You literally used it in your original question
`.withUrl("/hubs/chat", { accessTokenFactory: () => this.loginToken })`

Comment: @Brennan that's example from docs in javascript, but I couldnt find that class in C#

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/configuration?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=dotnet#configure-bearer-authentication-1